# Issues doing a clean install of windows 8 64 bit

Tags: partitioning, ssd, windows-8.1

I have a Asus K42JE laptop and recently installed a new M500 480GB SSD. Since adding the new SSD, I am unable to install windows 8.1 on it. I keep getting the following error

'We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the setup log files.'

I have tried partitioning/formatting the drive multiple times, made sure no other peripherals/usb drives/SD cards are attached to the laptop other than the bootable USB and done the following in diskpart but it did not help either.

```
Type LIST DISK
Type SELECT DISK <whatever disk number you have> 
Type CLEAN
Type CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY
Type ACTIVE
Type FORMAT FS=NTFS QUICK
Type ASSIGN
```

I initially thought there might be something wrong with my SSD so I went ahead and installed Ubuntu on it, which works perfectly fine. Its only Windows 8 that is giving me grief. The SSD is currently has 4 partitions.

Partitions 1 and 3 are for Ubuntu (ext4 and swap respectively) and 2 and 4 are for Windows (both NTFS)

Has anyone got any other tips and tricks that I can try?

Comment: Are you trying to install SO from DVD or USB?

Comment: I am trying to do the install using a bootable usb as my DVD drive is not functional.

Comment: _I think_ that's the problem. Currently I don't know why it happens, but happens. I had the same problem recently with two ssd in RAID1. I was unable to install the damn windows (windows 7 in my case). I tried -all-. And when I spent all my ideas, I thought that the only thing left was try to install it from an DVD instead of USB. And it worked at first try. I wasted like 4 hours -.-" Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try using an exteral HDD to do the install and see if that helps. If this does not work then I guess I will have to buy a new external optical drive.

Comment: Alsd make sure that your SSD is at slot 0 for SATA. I could not install Windows 8 since my HDD was at slot 1